# Html.Textbox value is not passing in url using javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I`m trying to pass the Html.Textbox value in the javascript url but it is giving an error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /WebProduct/Add/1
```

Below is my view class. from which i`m passing values to my controller.

**Edited**

```
 @model IEnumerable<DatabaseService_WebAPI.Models.ProductType>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tablets";

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#edit').click(function () {
                var name = $('#quantity').val();
                this.href = this.href + '&quantity=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
            });
        });

    </script>

}

<h2>Tablets</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "WebProduct", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Batch)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Expiry)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Batch)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Expiry)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("quantity")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new { name = item.Name, type = item.Type }, new { id = "edit" })

                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Create")
</div>
```

And its my controller method in which I`m passing the values.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(string quantity, string name, string type)
        {

            Product product = new Product();
            if (type=="Tablet")
            {

                //string order = type.Name + " " + type.Quantity;
                LocalDB tobj = ldb.LocalDBs.Single(s => s.User == User.Identity.Name);

                product.city = tobj.City;
                product.OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                product.ShopName = tobj.ShopName;
                product.User = tobj.User;
                //product.OrderDetail = order;

                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("TypeT", "WebProduct");
            }
            else if (type == "Syrup")
            {
                //string order = type.Name + " " + type.Quantity;
                LocalDB tobj = ldb.LocalDBs.Single(s => s.User == User.Identity.Name);
                product.city = tobj.City;
                product.OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                product.ShopName = tobj.ShopName;
                product.User = tobj.User;
             //   product.OrderDetail = order;

                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("TypeS", "WebProduct");
            }
            else
            {

              //  string order = type.Name + " " + type.Quantity;
                LocalDB tobj = ldb.LocalDBs.Single(s => s.User == User.Identity.Name);
                product.city = tobj.City;
                product.OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                product.ShopName = tobj.ShopName;
                product.User = tobj.User;
             //   product.OrderDetail = order;

                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("TypeC", "WebProduct");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

At this point i don't want to use button options. because i want to send database record and user's input to my controller`s method.

Comment: Is the URL of this page originally "/WebProduct/Add/1"? And you try to submit to "/WebProduct/Add/1?name=______"?

Comment: yes it is. "WebProduct" is my controller and "Add" is my method in controller. i think 1 is the ID. but i`m not sending it.

Comment: no i want to send /WebProduct/Add?name=xxx
i don`t understand where this 1 come from.

Comment: now i removed id=item.id from my actionlink now requested url is showing as /WebProduct/Add but the error is same The resource url is not found. however this is the url which is showing in the http://localhost:3325/WebProduct/Add?name=Panadol&type=Tablet

Comment: It wont be found because you are only passing in two parameters when it accepts 3.

Comment: I noticed you commented `@*@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "WebProduct",FormMethod.Post)){}*@`? So technically you're not sending a form. Check your HTML output and see if there is `<form>` tag

Comment: @MVCKarl yes u r right but i`m trying to send 3rd parameter in javascript method.

Comment: Yes can you delete all the lines that are commented out as that makes it difficult for us to resolve.

Comment: @JofryHS now i remove the comment but error is still same.

Comment: @MVCKarl i edited my View code.

Comment: Try changing the [HttpPost] to [HttpGet]

Comment: no, it not solved the issue.

Comment: Give my answer a try. The href must be something similar to localhost:3325/WebProduct/Add?name=Panadol&type=Tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that your

```
this.href == localhost:3325/WebProduct/Add?name=Panadol&type=Tablet
```

if that is correct then the following should work

```
$(function () 
 {
    $('#edit').click(function () 
    {
        var name = $('#quantity').val();

        var href = this.href;
        var splitHalfUrl = href.split('?');
        var splitQueryString = splitHalfUrl[1].split('&');
        window.location = "/WebProduct/Add?" + "quantity=" + encodeURIComponent(name) // Quantity
                                            "&" + splitQueryString[0] +   // Name
                                            "&" + splitQueryString[1];    // Type

     });
   });
```

Comment: can you tell me what the url is that you are getting from this.href

Comment: I have changed the query to fit. Once you give me an example of how the URL is coming out ill be able to try again

Comment: i used another method which is answer of my previous question. i used IList<ProducType> and a for loop. here is the question link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606405/html-textbox-is-not-passing-in-the-controller-in-actionlink/13607895#13607895
thx for giving such a precious time. now i aware of other method of href.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 this.href = this.href + '?quantity=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
```

your url will read something like

```
http://localhost:54745/WebProduct/Add?id=1&name=myname&type=mytype?quantity=4
```

two question marks can't be in the same url query string like this

UPDATE:
Your also in a foreach loop, meaning you will have multiple textboxes with id 'quantity' and multiple add links with id 'edit'

UPDATE 2:
add the parameter 'e' on the click event in order to call 'e.preventDefault()' this will stop the link from going to its URL.
then you will also need to set the window.location, rather than this.href (which is the link URL)

```
    $(function () {
        $('#edit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#quantity').val();
            window.location = this.href + '&quantity=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: i changed "?quantity=" to "&quantity=" but the error is still same. :(

Comment: I would suggest instead of using the id in the ActionLink, use a class (type @class = 'edit', as class is a keyword in C#), change your jquery to reflect this by making the selector a '.edit'.
Once this is done you will need to adjust the jquery to get the textbox closest to the actionlink - get the td parent, then find the quantity textbox under it. I would suggest changing the id of quantity box by using the id of the item in the foreach loop "quantity" + item.id, and use a class to find it with your javascript instead of your id

Comment: i used another method which is answer of my previous question. i used IList<ProducType> and a for loop. here is the question link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606405/html-textbox-is-not-passing-in-the-controller-in-actionlink/13607895#13607895

Answer (score 0):

Ok couple things I'd like to point out, you need to prevent default behavior on the ActionLink:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#edit').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $('#quantity').val();
                window.location = this.href + '&quantity=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
            });
        });

</script>
```

That should redirect your page to the url that you want: `localhost:port/WebProduct/Add?name=Name&type=Type&quantity=Quantity`

If you get another error, please check if your controller action is setup properly (spelling mistake can be a bitch).